# How to find timezone ID from IP address/country name in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

Can anyone please tell me if there is any way available in PHP to fetch timezone region  like('Asia/Calcutta') from IP Address or country name?

Description:

I am trying to set user timezone based on his/her country. I am getting user country from his IP address, But I need timezone region of that country like('Asia/Calcutta') to check whether DST is on in that country.
Can anyone please provide me some suitable solution in PHP?

Answer (score 6):

**Using IP Address**

Timezones follow sometimes quirky rules.  IP geolocation is anything but precise (notwithstanding the claims of some vendors).

Having said that, you can certainly find the city and country using a Geo IP product such as MaxMind's:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite

which includes a PHP module

http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

You can then use the MaxMind APIs to try and estimate the user's timezone

http://www.maxmind.com/app/faq#timezone

**Alternative**

If you want to rely on your user's clock rather than the IP address, jsTimezoneDetect works quite well (though it is not perfect).

https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home

**Summary**

Neither technique works perfectly in all cases.  Be sure you allow your user to correct any auto-generated timezone suggestion.

Comment: Maxmind link takes you to a generic FAQ page about all of their products - the timezone FAQ entry seems to have been taken down.

Comment: Try this https://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.com/p/get-client-date-time-using-ip-address.html

Answer (score 2):

This way you get time zone..

```
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("https://ipapi.co/json");
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';

//Timezone
echo $data['timezone'];
?>

//OUTPUT
Array
(
    [ip] => 2405:204:f089:d0e8:b1e7:a83e:9e2d:1bb5
    [city] => Bhubaneswar
    [region] => Odisha
    [region_code] => OR
    [country] => IN
    [country_name] => India
    [continent_code] => AS
    [postal] => 
    [latitude] => 20.2333
    [longitude] => 85.8333
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
    [utc_offset] => +0530
    [country_calling_code] => +91
    [currency] => INR
    [languages] => en-IN,hi,bn,te,mr,ta,ur,gu,kn,ml,or,pa,as,bh,sat,ks,ne,sd,kok,doi,mni,sit,sa,fr,lus,inc
    [asn] => AS55836
    [org] => Reliance Jio Infocomm Limited
)

Asia/Kolkata
```

Answer (score 1):

I consider a better idea is to finding out which timezone is set based on the user client setting. Maybe there is the situation that a user is in a timezone, which he doesn't want to be.

One simple possibility is to ask the user, but that's to easy.

With JavaScript you could find out the [offset in minutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) from UTC. Also you could find out, if the client is in a country with daylight saving time (DST) and if dst is active. This could be done, by comparing the time of two date objects, one with the month `January` and one with the month `July`.

```
var dst1, dst2, expires, hemisphere, now;

now = new Date(); expires = new Date(); dst1 = new Date(); dst2 = new Date();

expires.setTime(now.getTime() + 31536000000);
setCookie('timezone_offset', now.getTimezoneOffset(), expires, '/');

dst1.setDate(1);
dst1.setMonth(1);
dst2.setDate(1);
dst2.setMonth(7);

if (parseInt(dst1.getTimezoneOffset()) === parseInt(dst2.getTimeZoneOffset())) {
  setCookie('timezone_dst', 0, expires, '/');
} else {
  hemisphere = parseInt(d1.getTimezoneOffset()) - parseInt(d2.getTimezoneOffset());
  if ((hemisphere > 0 && parseInt(d1.getTimezoneOffset()) === parseInt(now.getTimezoneOffset())) || (hemisphere < 0 && parseInt(d2.getTimezoneOffset()) === parseInt(now.getTimezoneOffset()))) {
    setCookie('timezone_dst', '0', expires, '/');
  } else {
    setCookie('timezone_dst', '1', expires, '/');
  }
}
```

Read the cookie with PHP and interpreting the information of them with [timezone_name_from_abbr()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php):

```
$timezone = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $_COOKIE['timezone_offset'] * 60, $_COOKIE['timezone_dst']);
```

Comment: How would you use the 2 cookies though? Presumably your plan is to use DST or not depending on whether it's active, but the dates when DST transitions vary country to country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on the server side, you can do this with PHP:

```
$url = "https://ipsidekick.com/json";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($result, true);
print("It's " . $json["gmtOffset"] . " at " . $json["timeZoneName"]);
```

Note that this is synchronous.

Alternatively, if you can do it on the client side. You can use this with jQuery or equivalent:

```
$.get("https://ipsidekick.com/json", function(response) {
  console.log(response.ip +
    " It's " + response.gmtOffset +
    " from " + response.timeZoneName);
});
```

Disclaimer: I run [IP Sidekick](https://ipsidekick.com).