# How to get the Timezone in php based on client IP

Tags: php

I am using cakephp framework 
here i also successfully get the client ip

```
$client_ip=$this->RequestHandler->getClientIp();
$this->set(compact('client_ip'));
echo $client_id; e.g. 127.0.0.1
$tags = get_meta_tags("http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=$client_ip");
```

When i print the array

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tags)
```

my array becomes empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google IP Geolocation API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793655/google-ip-geolocation-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find timezone ID from IP address/country name in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219635/how-to-find-timezone-id-from-ip-address-country-name-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i found the solution:

```
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); 
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip")); 
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"]; 
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
```

Comment: Dear ryan. This website is used in many countries not for single country.so we can find the timezone dynamically.Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

An empty array from `get_meta_tags()` just means the file doesn't contain any meta tags. Try visiting the URL directly and inspect the HTML. It may not be what you think it is.

#### On a side note:

You should always use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) for debugging variables.

Comment: Can you Please how to get the timezone based on client id

Comment: When i remove the get_meta_tags. I get the following output : http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=127.0.0.1

Comment: Based on the client id or do you mean based on the client ***IP***?

Comment: Client IP address
 I already get the Client_ip by this function 
    $this->RequestHandler->getClientIp();

Comment: But i dont know how to get the timezone of that IP address

Comment: You would have to rely on looking up the IP address in a geoip database that also provides relevant timezone information or using a service like the one you appear to be *trying* to use. However, it should probably be noted that an IP address isn't likely to provide you with any accurate form of timezone information. The assumption you're making here is that the IP address whois information, accurately represents the user's physical location. That's not always the case.

Comment: I want to show the timezone in my website that website is accessed in many country. I want when user from US accessed the website the timezone of US will be displayed and accessed from India the timezone of india will be shown . If you have any code regarding my problem please  share it sherif . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't bother. Just send everything as a Unix timestamp to the client and have javascript format it to a date. The browser already knows what timezone it's in. There's no need for you to do all the juggling. Timezones are evil, complicated, confusing, cumbersome, convoluted, inaccurate, contradicting, evolving, perplexing artifacts of anarchy. *tl;dr;* Avoid them like the plague.